# Managing custom Acccept header in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a RESTful web service developed using Spring MVC and without any configuration I can return objects from my `@ResponseBody` annotated controller methods that get serialized to JSON. This works as soon as the Accept header in the request is not set or is `application/json`.

As I'm getting inspired by the GitHub API specification, I wanted to implement custom mime type for my API as [GitHub does](http://developer.github.com/v3/mime/), for example: `application/vnd.myservice+json`. But then I need to tell Spring MVC that my controllers can provide this mime type and that it should be serialized by Json (i.e org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView class).

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do exactly what is being done with `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`. Since it is not a final class, you can derive your converter from this one this way:

```
class MyCustomVndConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter{
    public MyCustomVndConverter (){
        super(MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.myservice+json"));
    }
}
```

then register your converter this way:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven> 
   <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
       <bean class="MyCustomVndConverter "/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

It should just work with these changes

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. I only needed to call `setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.myservice+json")));` instead of calling `super` constructor. BTW. it's a shame that MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter doesn't come with something like `super(MediaType.valueOf("application/*+json"))` in its contructor, because it would work out of the box then.