# Spring @ResponseBody and version specific Accept header

Tags: spring, rest

I want to serve different content types based on the `Accept` header I receive at a RESTful endpoint.

```
application/myapp-v1.0+json
application/myapp-v1.0+xml
```

Is there any way to do this with `@ResponseBody`? It seems like a convenient shortcut by allowing me to just return an object and let the `HttpMessageConverter` handle invoking Jackson but I just cannot get it working. 406 responses any time I wire up more than one MimeType.

For this iteration I've ended up querying the request header myself and returning the appropriate view handler myself, but I wouldn't mind revisiting this in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with Spring 3.1, you can do this using [`@RequestMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).  New to 3.1 for the `RequestMapping` annotation are these members:

1. [`consumes()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes%28%29) -- Allows you to filter by the `Content-type` request header.
2. [`produces()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces%28%29) -- Allows you to filter by the `Accept` request header.

There is also the ability to apply some simple expressions to make it more robust.

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"})

@RequestMapping(consumes = {"!text/plain"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something along the lines of what is suggested in this SO question:

[Managing custom Acccept header in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027668/managing-custom-acccept-header-in-spring-mvc/12030729#12030729)

```
class MyAppV1JsonConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter{
    public MyAppV1JsonConverter (){
        super(MediaType.valueOf("application/myapp-v1.0+json"));
        // OR setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.valueOf("application‌​/myapp-v1.0+json")));
    }
}
```

..