# In Spring Boot, adding a custom converter by extending MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter seems to overwrite the existing converter

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, media-type

I'm trying to create a converter for a custom media-type like `application/vnd.custom.hal+json`. I saw this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027668/managing-custom-acccept-header-in-spring-mvc), but it won't work since you don't have access to the protected constructor of `AbstractHttpMessageConverter<T>` (super class of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`). Which means that the following code does not work:

```
class MyCustomVndConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter {
    public MyCustomVndConverter (){
        super(MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.myservice+json"));
    }
}
```

However, the following does work and basically just mimics what the constructor actually does anyway:

```
setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(
    MediaType.valueOf("application‌​/vnd.myservice+json")
));
```

So I did this for my class, and then added the converter to my existing list of converters by following Spring Boot's documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters). My code basically looks like this:

```
//Defining the converter; the media-type is simply a custom media-type that is 
//still application/hal+json, i.e., JSON with some additional semantics on top 
//of what HAL already adds to JSON
public class TracksMediaTypeConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
    public TracksMediaTypeConverter() {
        setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(
            new MediaType("application‌​", "vnd.tracks.v1.hal+json")
        ));
    }
}

//Adding the message converter
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {

    ...    
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        return new HttpMessageConverters(new TracksMediaTypeConverter());
    }
}
```

As per the documentation, this should work. But what I noticed is that this has the effect of **replacing** the existing `MappingJackson2HttpMessageCoverter`, which handles `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and `application/*+json;charset=UTF-8`.

I verified this by attaching a debugger to my app and stepping through breakpoints inside Spring's `AbstractMessageCoverterMethodProcessor.java` class. There, the private field `messageConverters` contains the list of converters that have been registered. Normally, i.e., if I do not try to add my converter, I see the following coverters:

- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageCoverter` for `application/hal+json` (I'm assuming this is added by Spring HATEOAS, which I am using)
- `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`
- `StringHttpMessageConverter`
- `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`
- `SourceHttpMessageConverter`
- `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`
- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and `application/*+json;charset=UTF-8`
- `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`

When I add my custom media type, the second instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` gets replaced. That is, the list now looks like this:

- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for `application/hal+json` (I'm assuming this is added by Spring HATEOAS, which I am using)
- `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`
- `StringHttpMessageConverter`
- `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`
- `SourceHttpMessageConverter`
- `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`
- `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for `application/vnd.tracks.v1.hal+json` (the existing one has been replaced)
- `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`

I'm not entirely sure *why* this is happening. I stepped through the code and the only thing that really happens is that the no-args constructor of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is called (as it should be), which initially sets the supported media-types to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` and `application/*+json;charset=UTF-8`. After that, the list gets overwritten with the media-type that I provide.

What I cannot understand is why adding this media type should **replace** the existing instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that handles regular JSON. Is there some strange magic that is going on that does this?

Currently I have a workaround, but I don't like it very much since it's not that elegant and it involves duplication of code already in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

I created the following class (only changes from the regular `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` are shown):

```
public abstract class ExtensibleMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter<T> extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<T> implements GenericHttpMessageConverter<T> {

    //These constructors are not available in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, so
    //I provided them here just for convenience.    

    /**
     * Construct an {@code AbstractHttpMessageConverter} with no supported media types.
     * @see #setSupportedMediaTypes
     */
    protected ExtensibleMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    }

    /**
     * Construct an {@code ExtensibleMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter} with one supported media type.
     * @param supportedMediaType the supported media type
     */
    protected ExtensibleMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(MediaType supportedMediaType) {
        setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(supportedMediaType));
    }

    /**
     * Construct an {@code ExtensibleMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter} with multiple supported media type.
     * @param supportedMediaTypes the supported media types
     */
    protected ExtensibleMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(MediaType... supportedMediaTypes) {
        setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(supportedMediaTypes));
    }

    ...

    //These return Object in MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter because it extends
    //AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object>. Now these simply return an instance of
    //the generic type. 

    @Override
    protected T readInternal(Class<? extends T> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

        JavaType javaType = getJavaType(clazz, null);
        return readJavaType(javaType, inputMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public T read(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

        JavaType javaType = getJavaType(type, contextClass);
        return readJavaType(javaType, inputMessage);
    }

    private T readJavaType(JavaType javaType, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) {
        try {
            return this.objectMapper.readValue(inputMessage.getBody(), javaType);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not read JSON: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

I then use this class as follows:

```
public class TracksMediaTypeConverter extends ExtensibleMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter<Tracks> {
    public TracksMediaTypeConverter() {
        super(new MediaType("application", "application/vnd.tracks.v1.hal+json"));
    }
}
```

The registration of the converter in the configuration class is the same as before. With these changes, the existing instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` **is not** overwritten and everything works as I would expect.

So to boil everything down, I have two questions:

- Why is the existing converter being overwritten when I extend `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`?
- What is the right way to create a custom media-type converter that represents a semantic media-type that is still basically JSON (and therefore can be serialized and deserialized by `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Fixed in the latest version

Not sure when this was fixed, but as of `1.1.8.RELEASE`, this problem no-longer exists since it is using `ClassUtils.isAssignableValue`. Leaving the original answer here just for information.

---

There seem to be multiple issues at play here, so I'm going to summarize my findings as the answer. I still don't really have a solution for what I'm trying to do, but I'm going to talk to the Spring Boot folks to see if what's happening is intended or not.

### **Why is the existing converter being overwritten when I extend `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`?**

This applies to version `1.1.4.RELEASE` of Spring Boot; I haven't checked other versions. The constructor of the `HttpMessageConverters` class is as follows:

```
/**
 * Create a new {@link HttpMessageConverters} instance with the specified additional
 * converters.
 * @param additionalConverters additional converters to be added. New converters will
 * be added to the front of the list, overrides will replace existing items without
 * changing the order. The {@link #getConverters()} methods can be used for further
 * converter manipulation.
 */
public HttpMessageConverters(Collection<HttpMessageConverter<?>> additionalConverters) {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> defaultConverters = getDefaultConverters();
    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : additionalConverters) {
        int defaultConverterIndex = indexOfItemClass(defaultConverters, converter);
        if (defaultConverterIndex == -1) {
            converters.add(converter);
        }
        else {
            defaultConverters.set(defaultConverterIndex, converter);
        }
    }
    converters.addAll(defaultConverters);
    this.converters = Collections.unmodifiableList(converters);
}
```

Inside the `for` loop. Notice that it determines an index in the list by calling the `indexOfItemClass` method. That method looks like this:

```
private <E> int indexOfItemClass(List<E> list, E item) {
    Class<? extends Object> itemClass = item.getClass();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getClass().isAssignableFrom(itemClass)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Since my class extends `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` the `if` statement returns `true`. This means that in the constructor, we have a valid index. Spring Boot then **replaces** the existing instance with the new one, which is **exactly** what I am seeing.

### Is this desirable behavior?

I don't know. It doesn't *seem* to be and seems very strange to me.

### Is this called out explicitly in Spring Boot documentation anywhere?

Sort of. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters). It says:

> Any `HttpMessageConverter bean` that is present in the context will be added to the list of converters. You can also override default converters that way.

However, overriding a converter simply because it is a subtype of an existing one doesn't seem like helpful behavior.

### How does Spring HATEOAS get around this Spring Boot issue?

Spring HATEOAS' lifecycle is separate from Spring Boot. Spring HATEOAS registers its handler for the `application/hal+json` media-type in the `HyperMediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` class. The relevant method is:

```
private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> potentiallyRegisterModule(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
        if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverterCandidate = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = halConverterCandidate.getObjectMapper();
            if (Jackson2HalModule.isAlreadyRegisteredIn(objectMapper)) {
                return converters;
            }
        }
    }

    CurieProvider curieProvider = getCurieProvider(beanFactory);
    RelProvider relProvider = beanFactory.getBean(DELEGATING_REL_PROVIDER_BEAN_NAME, RelProvider.class);
    ObjectMapper halObjectMapper = beanFactory.getBean(HAL_OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN_NAME, ObjectMapper.class);

    halObjectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    halObjectMapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(relProvider, curieProvider));

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(HAL_JSON)); //HAL_JSON is just a MediaType instance for application/hal+json
    halConverter.setObjectMapper(halObjectMapper);

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> result = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>(converters.size());
    result.add(halConverter);
    result.addAll(converters);
    return result;
}
```

The `converters` argument is passed-in via this snippet from the `postProcessBeforeInitialization` method from the same class. Relevant snippet is:

```
if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) {
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) bean;
    adapter.setMessageConverters(potentiallyRegisterModule(adapter.getMessageConverters()));
}
```

### What is the right way to create a custom media-type converter that represents a semantic media-type that is still basically JSON (and therefore can be serialized and deserialized by `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`?

I'm not sure. Sub-classing `ExtensibleMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter<T>` (shown in the question) works for the time being. Another option would perhaps be to create a private instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` inside your custom converter, and simply delegate to that. Either way, I am going to open an issue with the Spring Boot project and get some feedback from them. I'll then update with answer with any new information.

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot docs explicitly states that adding a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` replaces the default value.

From [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper):

> Finally, if you provide any `@Beans` of type `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` then they will replace the default value in the MVC configuration. Also, a convenience bean is provided of type `HttpMessageConverters` (always available if you use the default MVC configuration) which has some useful methods to access the default and user-enhanced message converters.

Comment: I've mentioned that in my answer. Also, the question was about an older version.