# Spring Boot Produces text/csv, Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: spring, jhipster

I am trying to get my Spring Boot application to return `accept=text/csv`, I continue to get:

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation

I've added:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:${jackson_version}"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:${jackson_version}"
```

To my `build.gradle`, I am **NOT** using SpringMVC

and the handler looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/csv", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
    public List<RegistrationCode> exportToCsv(@ApiParam(name = "id", required = true, value = "string") @PathVariable String id, HttpServletResponse response) {

...
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
        csvFileName);
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
    response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=utf-8");
    return registrationCodes;
}
```

Curl example:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: text/csv' --header 'Authorization: Bearer ...' 'http://localhost:8080/api/1001/csv'
```

Message Converter:

```
public class CsvMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<List<RegistrationCode>> {

}
```

Example adding message converts (in traditional `applicationContext.xml`):

```
<util:list id="messageConverters">
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"
          p:objectMapper-ref="jsonObjectMapperFactory"/>
    <!--bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter"
          p:objectMapper-ref="xmlObjectMapperFactory"/-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean class="com.binding.CsvMessageConverter"/>
</util:list>
```

Comment: We tested with postman

Comment: @GaëlMarziou done I have my message converted (I just can't get it to register) I'll post the header of that.

Comment: I did not know you could use @RequestMapping without using Spring MVC. What's the benefit? You can't use springfox as well for swagger, right?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou correct, adding `@EnableWebMvc` or extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` as the majority of answers allude too breaks my application.

Comment: Sorry I can't help, you're quite far from JHipster generated code.

Comment: Looking at: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring, it should be possible to register this converter (as I would in a traditional `applicationContext.xml` file (I'll include an example)

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Adding the message converter
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {
    ...    
    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        return new HttpMessageConverters(new CsvMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

I was able to find some instructions for registering a convert here:

[In Spring Boot, adding a custom converter by extending MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter seems to overwrite the existing converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761845/in-spring-boot-adding-a-custom-converter-by-extending-mappingjackson2httpmessag#26766253)